# I need to combine four jQuery functions into one function that will be applied to a input text area within a loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a comment text box in a loop that I need to apply some [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) functions to.

1. I need to resize the text box according to text entered.
2. I need to check length of text. I do not want the user to enter more than 100 characters.
3. I need the user to be able to press enter and that will submit the comment.
4. I also need to submit the form without leaving the page.

I know how to do all functions individually. I would like to combine all the functions into one. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
    $i = 0; //For the id of the textarea

    while (/* Retrieve information from the database */)
    {
        $th_id = $row['th_id']; //id for the original comment/post.

        echo "<form method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='cb_id' value='".$th_id."' >
        <textarea onkeyup='addcom()'
                  onkeydown='addcom()'
                  placeholder='Press enter to comment'>
        </form>;
    }
?>
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function addcom()
        {
            var ch,l;
            ch = $('.addcom').val();
            l = ch.length;

            if (l == 30)
            {
                $('.addcom').css({'height':'40px'});
            }
            //More code until maximum number of characters is reached
            else if(l >= 100)
            {
                ch = ch.substring(0, 100);
                $('.addcom').val(ch);
            }
        }
    -->
</script>
```

How do I retrieve the information for the textfield and the hidden input field? Also, how do I trigger the event that if keycode 13 is pressed then the form gets submitted?

(The above JavaScript code is changing all the textarea in the loop as I expected.)

Comment: Items 2 and 3 don't require jQuery or Javascript. `<input maxlength='100'></input>`.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: You want stackoverflow to write your entire validation script..and then explain it to you? That's not how this site works.

Comment: @Jason Towne I was thinking more along the line of substring for 2. Like I said I know how to do all of the above individually but I was thinking that maybe all can be combined into one function......(jQuery, write less do more)

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I do not want stackoverflow to write my entire script I just wanted to know how to combine all of them into one function.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  Question is narrower in scope and prior work has been added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a jQuery plugin for the textboxes:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var txt = $(this);
        txt.on("keypress", function(event){
            // resize the text box according to the current value
            // if it is more than 100 characters get a substring of the first 100 characters
            // if the key press in the event is enter then submit the form using ajax
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Then in your original loop you can just attach this plugin to your text boxes:

```
var arrTextBoxes = [...];
for (var i = 0; i < arrTextBoxes.length; i++) 
{
    arrTextBoxes[i].myPlugin();
}
```

I didn't test any code here, but the premise is sound.
If you do this kind of stuff a lot there is another jQuery plugin called jQuery UI which has a widget factory that is perfect for creating reusable widgets (or extensible plugins) using their framework.

**Edit**

I have created a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AZdhw/1/) of the plugin.

I started off by modifying your HTML and removing the onkeyup and onkeydown events.

Old HTML:

```
<textarea onkeyup="addcom(e)" onkeydown="addcom(e)" class="com" placeholder="Press enter to submit"></textarea>
```

New HTML:

```
<textarea class="com" placeholder="Press enter to submit"></textarea>
```

Then I created the following jquery code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var txt = $(this);
        txt.on("keypress", function(event){

            // resize the text box according to the current value
            var l = txt.val().length;
            if(l < 30)
                txt.css("height", "20px");
            else if(l == 30)
                txt.css("height", "40px");
            else if(l == 60)
                txt.css("height", "60px");
            else if(l == 90)
                txt.css("height", "80px");

            // if it is more than 100 characters get a substring of the first 100 characters
            if(l >= 100)
                txt.val(txt.val().substring(0, 100));

            // if the key press in the event is enter then submit the form using ajax
            if(event.which == 13) {
                // Use $.get() or $.post() or $.ajax() to submit the form
            }
        });
    };
})( jQuery );

$("textarea.com").each(function(){
    $(this).myPlugin()
});
​
```

The first section will create the plugin.  I recommend renaming it so that it does not use the name `myPlugin`.  The plugin binds a keypress event to the textarea and performs your various actions.

The second section locates all of the textarea elements and inits the plugin for each textarea.

*NOTE:*
I did not write all of the code for you to do the form submittal.  If you need help with that, I would suggest creating another post on here asking specifically for help with that.

Comment: Why would you limit the length of the text box in javascript when you can limit it with the html?

Comment: Because this same thing would also work for textarea elements which don't support length limitations.

Comment: @JasonWhitted The function part I get. I simply attach all my codes inside the function event, right? Now the other part for the loop I do not get. Please take a look at the codes that I have provided, Where/how would I apply this plugin? And would the plugin only affect the current textbox that the user is typing in? With the above code, all the textboxes were affected.

Comment: In the example I gave, the `for` is applying the plugin to each text box in the `arrTextBoxes`.  Each textbox will have it's own plugin applied.  Each textbox would have its own keypress event wired up to it.  If you need additional help, I'll need you to create a jsfiddle containing the bare minimum code you are trying to get working.

Comment: @JasonWhitted I have never create a jsfiddle so I may need help with this before I can show the complete code that I am trying to append.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward.  It has a box for HTML, CSS, Javascript.  Once you press Run you can just provide me with the URL.

Comment: @JasonWhitted I was looking over jsfiddle and it seems that it does not support PHP coding, am I right? My original source code is in a loop using php.

Comment: That is correct.  Just hard code a few of the html elements in the HTML section as if php had generated them.

Comment: @JasonWhitted here is the link of what I have so far [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwaight/AZdhw/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21547/discussion-between-bryan-and-jason-whitted)